# How could this string have been produced?

Tags: json, encoding

I am trying a sort of multi-step programming/IT challenge, which involves understanding the method used to encode the stuff, and then applying the decoded information to access a site.

There were steps where clues were text written in ascii codes, some base64 encoded stuff and now I have come to a JSON string, which supposedly holds a password and which is:

```
a:1:{s:8:"backdoor";s:50:"323031362e30362e32382031363a31323a3034:AdzLwepase2";}
```

Now, the long string of numbers is a hex encoded timestamp, but what about the actual password? Simply using the text after the colon does not work, is there some sort of well-known two-way en/de-coding that could produce something like this? None come to mind at the moment, though the form of the text looks vaguely familiar.

Comment: That is *not* JSON.

Comment: Allright. thanks. Any idea what could this be?